Playwright using Mobile Safari, having issues with changes after requests
I have a test where I compare an old and a new price after a request is made. The test passes on Mobile Chrome, but on Mobile Safari the comparison is done before the view is getting updated.
  const productCardPriceDescending = await getFirstProductPrice(); //getting first value
  await openFacetsButton.click();
  await facetListItemSort.click();
  await page.getByTestId('facetSortItem_PRICE_ASCENDING').click(); //results in a request to grapqhl
  await facetCloseButton.click();
  await expect(facetWrapperClosed).toBeVisible(); //these is to wait and confirm that facet is closed
  const productCardPriceAscending = await getFirstProductPrice(); //getting updated value
  console.log(productCardPriceDescending, productCardPriceAscending); // gives me same value, should be different

  expect(productCardPriceAscending).not.toBe(productCardPriceDescending); //fails saying its the same value

I've tried using await page.waitForResponse to wait for the response, but does not work. I even manually satt in a wait page.waitForTimeout(5000);, which with --headed flag I could see the new updated value, but the tests still is stuck on the old. With tracing I can also see that the value is not updated even though in the tests it clearly was. Is this maybe a known issue with Playwright and safari?
We use NextJS + Apollo graphql

Please share a complete, runnable [mcve] with a package.json, full code and a website under test. All functions like getFirstProductPrice need to be defined for this to be answerable. Thanks.
